# Modifying Joomla's feedback message

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, language, administration

How can I modify the feedback message returned by joomla?

What method do I need to override in order to extend the functionality that renders this message?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple language string which can be overriden in the language manager.
For that go to the Language Manager and there the "Overrides" submenu.
Click the "New" button.
You can use the search to find the language key you need to override. However I usually just search the ini files in the language directory directly.

In your specific case, the only one I found which is matching is from Smart Search. So you're looking to override `COM_FINDER_N_ITEMS_PUBLISHED_1`.

Comment: Thanks, Bakual for the answer I know that in language.ini I can overriden the value and yes I can navigate to the language directory and change the value. my concern now is how does joomla set the system messages? take a loot at this language string : **COM_ARTICLE_FILES_N_ITEMS_PUBLISHED="%d Successfully published**
as you can see there is **%d** prefixed in the value string now I want to dynamicaly set the value of that string.

Comment: The message is generated in `JControllerAdmin->publish()` https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/legacy/controller/admin.php#L212
As you see it uses `JText::plural()` and it passes in the count as a second argument.
`JText::plural` automatically creates a suffix to the language key, depending on the available plural forms in a given language. So in case there is only one item, it appends `_1` to the key.

Comment: Which part of my component to include that?

Comment: As long as your controller extends `JControllerAdmin` and calls the parent `publish` method (or doesn't override it), it will be handled automatically. The `$this->text_prefix` equals to the name of your component (eg `COM_FOO`) if not specified otherwise.
Otherwise you need to do this call yourself similar to what `JControllerAdmin` does.

Comment: ahaha this is great I use PHPStrom to jump for the class definition instead of using Sublime I need to find the path of that class. anyway thanks for this man.